# How can I create my own ListView UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

Ok so I have a table cell that I would like to use in this custom ListView UserControl, so I was wondering how exactly do you set one of these up and how do you call the cells to be my custom ones? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Separate the UI from your data so you don't fall into this bear trap.  You can use the Tag property if you need a back-link to your data objects.

Comment: Just create your UserControl with custom UI, then create new UserControl instance and ADD it to ListView.Controls. Very simple

Answer (score 3):

The ListView control is a b**ch, so if you are really planning to get your hands dirty with it, be prepared for a great big mess.

If you would prefer a ready-made solution, I will point you to this one: [CodeProject - ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx)

Comment: I disagree. ListView is very simple to handle.

Answer (score 1):

We at ComponentOwl made custom ListView control called [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview). (Or maybe you can be interested in the freeware edition [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express)).

You can also try the suggested ObjectListView.

The ListView control is -very- complex and contains myriads of little features all we had to implement. So I recommend you to look for a finished 3rd party control, since coding this is challenging (the BetterListView hit 40K lines of code only to meet requirements of ListView, now having about 80K+ lines of code!)